# Python variables format changes inside an IF while the first condition is ok

Tags: python

I am doing a very simple aplication of calculating a cost, and I want to have a Radiobutton where I can choose the currency.

I am wondering what is the problem here, because whith the first condition(Run in EUR), everything goes well, but if there is the second condition, I got the problem:

```
 File "C:\Users\Iker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Iker\eclipse-workspace\Prueba2\Prueba2.py", line 128, in <lambda>
    Button_1 = Button(root, text="Calcular", padx=20, pady=10, command=lambda:calcular(Moneda.get()))   File "C:\Users\Iker\eclipse-workspace\Prueba2\Prueba2.py", line 71, in calcular
    Beneficio_Bruto_EUR = Label(root, width=20, borderwidth=5, text="%.2f€"%Beneficio_Bruto/d) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

I really don't get it, because if there a problem defining the variables, shouldn't be in the `if` and `else` the same?

```
def calcular(Moneda):
    a=float(Precio_de_venta.get())
    b=float(Portes.get())
    c=float(Precio_de_compra.get())
    d=float(1.04)

    #Beneficio Bruto
    Beneficio_Bruto=a-c-b-(a*0.1)-((a*0.029)+0.35)
    Beneficio_Brutolbl=Label(root, text="Beneficio Bruto")
    Beneficio_Brutolbl.grid(row=3, column=0)
    if Moneda == 0:
        Beneficio_Bruto_EUR = Label(root, width=20, borderwidth=5, text="%.2f€"%Beneficio_Bruto)
        Beneficio_Bruto_EUR.grid(row=3, column=1)
        Beneficio_Bruto_USD = Label(root, width=10, borderwidth=5, text="%.2f USD"%(Beneficio_Bruto*d))
        Beneficio_Bruto_USD.grid(row=3, column=2)
    elif Moneda == 1:
        Beneficio_Bruto_EUR = Label(root, width=20, borderwidth=5, text="%.2f€"%Beneficio_Bruto/d)
        Beneficio_Bruto_EUR.grid(row=3, column=2)
        Beneficio_Bruto_USD = Label(root, width=10, borderwidth=5, text="%.2f USD"%(Beneficio_Bruto))
        Beneficio_Bruto_USD.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis:

```
Beneficio_Bruto_EUR = Label(root, width=20, borderwidth=5,
                            text="%.2f€" % (Beneficio_Bruto/d))
```

String formatting is always applied before operations:

```
>>> '%d' % (4 * 2)
'8'
>>> '%d' % 4 * 2
'44' 
>>> '%d' % (4 / 2)
'2'
>>> '%d' % 4 / 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: But why the first condition is working and the second one not? That is what I can't understand

Comment: @unkim the first one is working because it has parentheses: `text="%.2f USD"%(Beneficio_Bruto*d)`, the second one is not working because it doesn't have parentheses